# How to clear the whole screen in tkinter and get new data on click of menu bar item

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I am trying to make a basic software wherein, I have a menu bar and on click of each item, I want a whole different layout of the window.

I dont want to open a new screen as some of you may confuse instead I want to make the screen clear up and new data as per menu bar option click to open in the same window.

If you can guide me through this, It would be of great help.
I am attaching my code below:)

```
from tkinter import *
def doNothing():
    print("Ok, I wont")

#---------------------------Initializing----------------------------------------
root =Tk()

def clear():
    list = root.grid_slaves()
    print(list)
    for l in list:
        l.destroy()

#-----setting screen size by dynamically getting height and width of screen-----
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry(str(screen_width)+"x"+str(screen_height))
root.config(background='#2b2b2b')


def home():
    labelfont = ('helvetica', 100)

    label_one = Label(root, text = 'Home page')
    label_one.config(fg='white',bg="#2b2b2b")  
    label_one.config(font=labelfont)        
    label_one.pack()





#------------------------adding menu bar to the window-------------------------
def menucall():
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    subMenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
    subMenu.add_command(label="New Loan",command=newLoan)
    subMenu.add_command(label="New Invoice",command=doNothing)
    subMenu.add_separator()
    subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=home)


#-----------------------------------File---------------------------------------
#---------------------------------New Loan-------------------------------------

def newLoan():
    labelfont = ('helvetica', 100)
    label_one = Label(root, text = 'FinanCo New Loan').grid(row=0)
    label_one.config(fg='white',bg="#2b2b2b")  
    label_one.config(font=labelfont)        
    label_one.pack()

#---------------------------Main--------------------------------
menucall()



root.mainloop()
```

The screen doesn't clear instead the new items just keep getting added below each other.

Comment: put widgets in Frames and then you will have to only show/hide frames - `pack()/pack_forget()`. And keep frames in global variables - created outside function.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe a lazy approach but try to hide the items like far away the screen (x=-100000, y=-100000)

when clicking menu1

```
#change all the items that you don't need in menu1
menu2label1.config(x=-100000,y=-100000)
menu2label2.config(x=-100000,y=-100000)
etc..
```

when clicking menu2

```
#change all the items that you don't need in menu2
menu1label1.config(x=-100000,y=-100000)
menu1label2.config(x=-100000,y=-100000)
etc..
```

In more professional approach is try to stick the items in a canvas and just hide them when you clicking each menu.

I haven't tried the professional approach to be honest, but it's worth the try.

Comment: That would prove useful if I have only one other page than main page. But in my project I am planning to create multiple options which will make this approach futile as I would not know which page the user is in and which page is going to go.

Comment: If there is any approach to find all the elements in the screen and then completely remove it or destroy it, It would prove helpful. Thank you:)

Comment: found you a helpful reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk and the closest answer to your problem :)
It changes the contents of the window to another one